# Android SQLite insert statement error

Tags: android-sqlite

In my database I modified my table. previously it had 2 columns excluding id. Now it has 3 columns excluding id. So whenever i add an tuple it shows error.
For adding tuple i ve called addContact function

```
      private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 25;


    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactsManager";

    // Contacts table name
    private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS1 = "contacts";

    // Contacts Table Columns names

    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_PH_NO = "phone_number";
    private static final String KEY_UNIQUE = "unique";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS1 + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_UNIQUE + " INTEGER," + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT " + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS1);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
     */

    // Adding new contact
    void addContact(Contact contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName()); // Contact Name
        values.put(KEY_UNIQUE, contact.getUnique());
        values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber()); // Contact Phone

        // Inserting Row
         //giving error at following line
        db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS1, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }
```

//error is Error inserting name=21:58 unique=1717 phone_number=null3
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "unique": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO contacts(name,unique,phone_number) VALUES (?,?,?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UNIQUE` is a keyword in SQL and cannot be used as an identifier as such.

Rename the column name to something like `isunique` or similar, and uninstall your app so that the modified `onCreate()` is actually run.